# Excel: How to sort or order domains at the begining second-level then third-level?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Excel table with a list of different domains. I want to sort or order list like first begins with the second-level domains then go the third-level domains. Is it possible to sort Excel table like this?

Example with no-sorting list:

- **example1.blog.com**
- **example1.com**
- **example2.site.com**
- **example3.site.com**
- **example4.com**

I want to sort like this:

- **example1.com**
- **example4.com**
- **example1.blog.com**
- **example2.site.com**
- **example3.site.com**

I can't find any information how to sort Excel table like thos

Comment: Create some extra columns of the parts by splitting on the '.' char.  These can be hidden columns if you want.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-functions-49ec57f9-3d5a-44b2-82da-50dded6e4a68

Then follow this to order by multiple columns: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-sort-column-row-custom-list/

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(r, A1:A5,
     TAKE(
          SORT(
               HSTACK(
                      LEN(r)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(r,".","")),
                      TEXTAFTER(r,"."),
                      r),
               {1,2,3})
          ,,-1))
```

It first creates an array of the count of dots per row,

To the right of that a column of the text after the first dot,

Finally an array of the actual range values.

It sorts the stacked arrays (by dots, then text after the first dot and then the range values) and keeps the last column of the array, which is your result.